# Проблема с плагином wordpress navxt при исползовании polylang

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Здравствйте, использующий плагин Polylang Wordpress для перевода, и плагин breadcrumbs navxt для хлебных крошек, но у меня есть проблема. Мой язык сайта по умолчанию - русский. На этом языке нет проблем с хлебных крошек. Но когда я добавляю новый язык и выбираю его, возникает одна проблема. Например, я перехожу на страницу, это должно выглядеть так:

Имя домашней страницы на этом языке, который я выбираю> Название статьи(или записи).

Но это происходит так:

Название домашней страницы на русском языке> Название домашней страницы на другом языке> Название статьи

Как я могу это исправить?

P.S для отображения имени главной страницы в плагине Breadcrumbs, я использую этот код в functions.php:

```
add_filter('bcn_breadcrumb_title', function($title, $type, $id) {
    if ($type[0] === 'home') {
        $title = get_the_title(get_option('page_on_front'));
    }
    return $title;
}, 42, 3);
```

Comment: Страницы разных языков связаны?

Comment: Я за тебя погуглил,  зашел на оф сайт плага ХБ и увидел это https://mtekk.us/extensions/breadcrumb-navxt-polylang-extensions/

Comment: Sevlad, Я в курсе этого расширения. Оно как видишь платное.

Comment: Страницы языков связаны.

Answer (score 1):

для начала вам нужно убедится, что в настройках Polylang - Strings translations у вас есть перевод для поля Site Title.

далее нужно отредактировать файл плагина **class.bcn_breadcrumb_trail.php**

Найти в нем функцию **do_home**() и в ней используя функции Polylang: **pll_current_language**(), **pll_default_language**(), **pll_home_url**() изменить формирование пункта с главной страницей в хлебных крошках.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно использовать javascript (в примере ниже меняем для русского языка)

```
if(document.documentElement.lang == "ru-RU") {
    $('.home').children('span').text('Главная');
    var text = $('.home').attr('href');
    text += /ru/;
    $('.home').attr('href', text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

добавил такой костыль внутри файла **class.bcn_breadcrumb_trail.php** внутри функции **do_home()** сделав проверку, если язык английский, то установи кастомную тему:

```
if($force_link || ($is_current_item && $this->opt['bcurrent_item_linked']) || ($is_paged && $this->opt['bpaged_display']))
    {
    if(pll_current_language() == 'en') {
        $breadcrumb->set_template('
            <span property="itemListElement" typeof="ListItem">
              <a property="item" typeof="WebPage" title="Main" href="http://acoustic.fi/" class="%%type%%" bcn-aria-current>
                <span property="name">Main</span>
              </a>
              <meta property="position" content="%%position%%">
            </span>');
    } else {
        $breadcrumb->set_template($this->opt['Hhome_template']);
    }
    $breadcrumb->set_linked(true);
}
```